# How to override property's value:true with an attribute in Polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

In polymer if I have a property called `value` with type `Boolean` and default value `true`:

```
static get properties() {
  return {
    value: {
      type: Boolean,
      value: true
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to set the value to `false` with HTML attribute?

e.g. all of these samples intrepret the `value` property as `true`:

```
<my-element></my-element>
<my-element value></my-element>
<my-element value="false"></my-element>
<my-element value="[[false]]"></my-element>
<my-element value="{{false}}"></my-element>
<my-element value="{{!constructor}}"></my-element>
```

Here's a sample codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KWdWRm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, unfortunately you cannot bind a `false` value to a Boolean property, as the Polymer [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#configuring-boolean-properties) explain:

> For a Boolean property to be configurable from markup, it must default to `false`. If it defaults to `true`, you cannot set it to `false` from markup, since the presence of the attribute, with or without a value, equates to `true`. This is the standard behavior for attributes in the web platform.
>
> If this behavior doesn't fit your use case, you can use a string-valued or number-valued attribute instead.